# Wordpress menu/widget placement

Tags: php, html, wordpress, responsive-design

Im working on this site http://www.maneki-xxxxxxxx.com/ and im trying to put the menu under the logo, but if im not mistaken this is also a widget?

What would be the best way to go about this without breaking the theme?

Im new to the game so im slowly learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they not two different menus ?

Comment: Yes. I have removed one menu and just building the menu from the left.

Comment: After i did that fix this one showed up: http://www.maneki-nekocasino.com/verajohn-review/  The purple field :/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has number of plugins available. 
I can suggest plugin, may be your doubts are clear.

[Adavance menu widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/)

[Custom Menu Wizard](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-menu-wizard/screenshots/)

Comment: I would like to move the entire menu under the logo i have added.

Comment: yeah then simply add this plugin in widget area and called the function in your file <?php dynamic_sidebar('your widget name'); ?>

Comment: Is it possible to move the existing menu down a notch without breaking the theme?

Comment: may be your purchased theme will provide the functionality to put menu  below logo. but chances are less. however you can do it via change in css else called nav_menu function after logo. There is  no way to change location without editing theme

Comment: What would be the best way to move it in nav_menu?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by configuring this:

```
.navleft {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```